# em.createQuery keeps returning null

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have this application which i use JSF 2.0 and EclipseLink, i have entities created for a database made in MySQL, Created these entities using netbeans 7.1.2, it gets created automaticly.

Then i use session beans to work with these entities, the thing is the `em.createQuery` always returns a null, though I checked NamedQueries in the entities and they perfectly match

a sample from the entities named queries:-

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userId = :userId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email"),
```

notice how i use this findByEmail query in the session bean :-

```
public Users findByEmail(String email){
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String find = "Users.findByEmail";
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(find);
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        Users user = (Users) query.getSingleResult();
```

but it always returns null from this em.createNamedQuery, i tried using .createQuery first but it also was no good.

the stacktrace of the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.readme.entities.sessionBeans.UsersFacade.findByEmail(UsersFacade.java:48)
    at com.readme.user.signup.SignupBean.checkAvailability(SignupBean.java:137)
    at com.readme.user.signup.SignupBean.save(SignupBean.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

What Seems To Be The Problem Here ?

Comment: This problem is not related with JSF.

Comment: How are you obtaining the `EntityManager`?

Comment: I used @PersistenceContext annotation to get the em

Answer (score 1):

If `em.createNamedQuery(find)` really is the statement that throws NullPointerException in your case, then something rather odd is happening.

Most likely NullPointerException is thrown when you use for the first time `em` reference in `em.getTransaction().begin()`. If that is the case, then a very common reason is that your entity manager is not injected, because injection does work only in managed classes (for details, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536483/entitymanagerfactory-not-being-injected-using-persistenceunit/10537076#10537076)). If you created a session bean via a new operation, then it is not managed.

Other common reason is that @Persistenceontext annotation is simply missing.

Comment: i tried everything but it keeps showing this error, weird thing also is that it used to work before i update the database